# Rewriting a linear transformation from formula to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection

This is a question from my exam that I just cannot figure out how to do it. Thank you for helping me in advance. I will try to write it in here but it will be easier to understand using the image I added to this thread:

Show that for normal vector $n = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ using the formula $f_n(x) = x-2\left(\frac{x\cdot n}{n\cdot n}n\right)$ leads to the following matrix:
$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
-a^2+b^2+n3^2&-2ab&-2ac\\  
-2ba&a^2-b^2+c^2&-2bc\\  
-2ca&-2cb&a^2+b^2-c^2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

[The original assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Wjx.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The formulas in the question are wrong, doesn't fit the picture

Answer (score 1):

You only have to compute $f_n(1,0,0)$, $f_n(0,1,0)$ and $f_n(0,0,1)$ and express the results in columns. For example
$$
f_n(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)-\frac{2 n_1}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2}(n_1,n_2,n_3)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2}(-n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2,-2n_1n_2,-2n_1 n_3)
$$
which is the first column of your matrix.